# Callback Url for twitter developer (tweepy)

Tags: callback, tweepy, twitter-oauth, callbackurl

I am making an real time NLP model, for which I'm trying to stream data from twitter using tweepy. I'm new to APIs and the twitter developer authentication is asking for call_back url and website url. Now, I don't have a website, I just need data which I'll save in a dataframe. What URL should I give for callback and website?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use an App-Only OAuth 2.0 authentication (or only the tokens of your dev account), you don't need a callback URL since this is supposed to be the URL where your users would have been redirected after having authorizing your application in a Twitter page.

If the field is mandatory in the form, just input localhost (this is standard for dev env anyway).